# Print SwaggerUI path/url to console on startup with Springdoc

Tags: springdoc

Is there a robust way to print the SwaggerUI path to the console on startup when using springdoc?

I'm looking for a way that is robust to configuration changes of the `springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled` and `springdoc.swagger-ui.path`. It feels like this should be solvable with the framework without lots of custom code.

Answer (score 0):

springdoc-openapi endpoints are like any spring other controllers.
In spring you just need to set the right logging level of your application.

For example:

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        web: TRACE
```